# How do I deploy a local dynamodb instance, including all the files, to AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a local `dynamodb` instance with a few tables and a lot of items for each table. This is running on localhost:8000, and I'm interacting with it directly using the AWS console (ex: `aws dynamodb` create-table, etc.).

Is there an easy way to deploy all these tables directly to my remote dynamodb AWS accounts?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: I couldn't find an automatic way of doing it, but you can manually create the tables online and scan the local database in boto3, before adding all the scanned objects to the right tables.

Comment: In case it's useful to you, I just found about this tool: https://github.com/bchew/dynamodump thanks to a reply on a thread I posted today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54842442/transfer-tables-and-table-data-in-local-dynamodb-instance-to-aws-hosted-instance/54843185