# Transfer tables and table data in local DynamoDB instance to AWS hosted instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, clone, transfer

Is there a function, utility, or otherwise for transferring all the tables and their data from an instance of DynamoDB running on my local computer, to a production level, AWS hosted DynamoDB instance?  My local computer is an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS instance and I need to transfer all the content from my local DynamoDB instance I used during development and clone that data to an instance I've recently created on AWS.

I found this Stack Overflow post on the same subject but it has no answers:

[How do I deploy a local dynamodb instance, including all the files, to AWS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53648478/how-do-i-deploy-a-local-dynamodb-instance-including-all-the-files-to-aws)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this could be your solution -> https://github.com/bchew/dynamodump

As per docs;

> Simple backup and restore script for Amazon DynamoDB using boto to
>   work similarly to mysqldump.
>
> Suitable for DynamoDB usages of smaller data volume which do not
>   warrant the usage of AWS Data Pipeline for backup/restores/empty.
>
> dynamodump supports local DynamoDB instances as well (tested with
>   DynamoDB Local).

Comment: Is that a private repo?  I get a 404 error when I follow that link.